# My ajax call wont work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WvGR.png)

```js
$("select#pieces").change(function() {
  $('div#pop').html('');
  for (var c=0, t = $("select#pieces").val();c<t;c++) {
    $('div#pop').append("<input type='Text'  name='piecex[]' autocomplete='off' required placeholder='Piece Info' required style='width:415px;text-transform:uppercase; margin-bottom:10px; '>");
  }
});
```

my ajax call wont work can anyone help me please. Im trying to post my form data to my php script that will run my query's. I have tried a few methods of gathering the data ready to be posted but nothing happens when i press submit.

```js
$("#submit").click(function(){

// Tried this previously
//var data = {}; $('form').find('input').forEach(function(input){ data[$(input).attr('name')] = $(input).val(); });

 var $inputs = $('#Form :input');

    var data = {};
    $inputs.each(function() {
        data[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });


      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'checkBeforePrint.php',
            data: { data
            },
            success: function(e) {
                  if (e.r === true) {
                  } else if (e.r === false) {
                  }
            },
            dataType: "json"
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id = "form" class = "form">
<table>
<tr>
 <td>Reference *</td>
 <td>
  <input type='number' id='a' name='reference_end1' required size='7' maxlength='1'  style='width:90px;font-family:Century Gothic; text-transform:uppercase; '>
  
  <input type='Text' id='b'  name='reference_end2' required size='7' maxlength='3'  style='width:140px;font-family:Century Gothic; text-transform:uppercase;'>
  
  <input type='number' id='c'  name='reference_end3' required size='7' maxlength='6'  style='width:190px;font-family:Century Gothic; text-transform:uppercase;'>
  
  <!-- inputs combined above -->
  
 <input type='hidden' id='reference_end'  name='reference_end'> 
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>

</br>
<div class ="bookinform">


<table>
<tr>
 <td>Name of Driver *</td>
 <td>
  <input type='Text' name='driver_name' required autocomplete="off" size='7' maxlength='25' style='width:250px;font-family:Century Gothic'>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr>
 <td>Vehicle Reg *</td>
 <td>
  <input type='Text' name='Vehicle_Reg' required autocomplete="off" size='7' maxlength='15' style='width:250px;font-family:Century Gothic; text-transform:uppercase;'>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td valign='top'>Haulier *</td><td valign='top'><input type='Text' id="query" name='haulier' required style='width:250px; font-family:Century Gothic; text-transform:uppercase;'>

<tr><td></td></tr>
<!--
# Blank out the auto-complete haulier as per Richard Walkers request
onKeyUp="GetResults(document.getElementById('query').value)" 
        <div id="results" class="box">
        </div>
-->


</td></tr>


<tr><td>Destination *</td><td><input type='Text' id="query2"  name='destination' required style='width:250px; text-transform:uppercase;'></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</br>
<div class ="bookinform">
<table>
<tr><td>Pieces *</td>
<td><select id = "pieces" name='pieces' required style='width:320px; font-family:Century Gothic;'>
<option> Select Number Of Pieces </option>
<?php
 $count = 1;
 while ($count<=100) {
  echo "<option value='".$count."'>".$count."</option>";
  $count++;
 };
?>
</select></td></tr>

<!--<tr><td>Labels</td><td>-->
<select name='labels' style="display:none">
<option value='0'>SAME AS PIECES</option>
<?php
 $count = 1;
 while ($count<=100) {
  echo "<option value='".$count."'>".$count."</option>";
  $count++;
 };
?>
</select>

<!--</td></tr>-->

    
</table>

</br>

<!-- JQUERY POPULATES IN POP pieces fields-->
<div id = "pop"></div>

</div>



<div class ="bookinformbtn">
<div class ="bookinform">


<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
<!--</br></br>
<button class="resetref" style="width:100%;font-family:Century Gothic; color:#FFC200 ; font-weight: bold;">Next REF</button>-->
</br></br>
<form action="http://cmlgrn:8629/index.php?BookInA">
  <input type='submit' value="EXIT" style='width:100%;font-family:Century Gothic; color:red; font-weight: bold;'>
</form>
```

Comment: looks like the ajax call itself is working (according to chrome dev tools), but because it's running on stacksnippets i cant see what the output is.. could you show the code from checkbeforeprint.php

Answer (score 1):

Attach to the forms `submit` event, call `preventDefault` on the event to stop a normal submit (page refresh), and use `serialize()` to generate the post data from the form:

```
$('#form').submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.post('checkBeforePrint.php', $(this).serialize(), function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

EDIT as pointed out in comments, you will need to change your submit button to type `submit`

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Clicking an input of type button has no default behaviour. So i'm really not sure why form is submitted in first place

Comment: this just gives me  a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: @user5554551 Yeah i missed a couple of closing brackets. Fixed

Comment: It sends everything apart from the piecex[] ..... I have added the javascript that is used to populate these fields above.

Comment: @user5554551 I cant see a form field with that name?

Comment: look in the piece of javascript iv just added to this post please

Comment: That should work fine, however it looks like you have some invalid html (eg an erroneous `</td></tr>` under the section that reads `# Blank out the...`. Broken html can cause weird bugs like this, causeing the ndynamic form elements to be considered ouitside of the form, and therefor ignored

Comment: my piecex[] data is being ignored Here is my full code - https://jsfiddle.net/bm97mgks/

Comment: @user5554551 Yes, as i said, you have broken html - a bunch of mismatched opening and closing tags, for example your 1st form tag is opening inside `<div class ="bookinform"` but that div is closed long before the closing form tag. You cant have a parent element close before its children. There are probably more similar errors. Until you fix your html, you javascript will act weird.

Comment: @user5554551 Great, glad i could help you get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){

var $inputs = $('#Form :input');

var data = {};
$inputs.each(function() {
    data[this.name] = $(this).val();
});

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
        url: 'checkBeforePrint.php',
            data: { data
            }
        }).done(function (e) {
              if (e.r === true) {
              } else if (e.r === false) {
              }
        });

   });
```

Comment: Clicking an input of type button has no default behaviour

Comment: @A.Wolff Very true - i presumed as it was a submit button.